# How to make a button's onclick function in one webpage execute a function in another webpage without php

Tags: javascript, html

In my main html page, I have the following code:

```
<p class="text" id="time">00:00</p>
```

In my other html page, I have the following code:

```
<button onclick="resettime()">RESET TIME</button>
```

They both link to the same javascript page, which has the code:

```
function timeIncrement()
{
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = +mins+":"+secs;
  if(secs==60)
  {
    mins+=1;
    secs = 0;
  }
}

var timecheck = setInterval(timeIncrement,1000);

function resettime()
{
  clearInterval(timecheck);
  mins  = 0;
  secs = 0;
  timecheck = setInterval(timeIncrement,1000);
}
```

Clicking the button doesn't reset the time to 0:0, so it doesn't work, so I was wondering if there's any way I can do this without going into php. I'm new to html/js, so sorry if this is a repeat, couldn't find a similar one.

Comment: are you asking how to make resettime() work or how to call it from a second page?

Comment: @Cruiser How to make it work, as the problem is with the onclick being on a button in a different page, right?

Comment: unless there's more code you haven't shown, timeIncrement() has no knowledge of the min and sec variables. To call resettime() from another page you'd need to send a GET request to the second page and parse the url, then call resettime() based on the values passed

Comment: Why would you want the rest button to be on a different page to the actual timer? Or am I just being stupid?

Comment: No, I do want it exactly like that. I'm making this for a weird situation where     the webpages are used offline and I need to use one webpage to alter content on the timer webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Two html means two windows. if you want to execute script from one window to another window, you should have the other window's object and both window should have document.domain. for having reference of another window

in main html add the following

```
<script>window.open("other.html");//other html will open automatically</script>
```

in other html, change the code to following

```
<button onclick="resettimeinMainHtml()">RESET TIME</button>

<script>function resettimeinMainHtml(){window.opener.resettime();// will reset in mail html}</script>
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work, sorry :( I think this has to do with the second document not having access to the vars mins and secs, maybe?

Comment: declare mins and secs globally and try

Comment: It should work :O Can you tell what error you got in console.